# Ajax call give success response only if Dev tool is open in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with ajax call.It give success response in all the browser except chrome.If the chrome's developer tool is opened then the same call will give success. Please help i'm stuck with this..

```
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: request,
    headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
    method: Get,
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    },
    success: function (response) {
        returnValue = response;
    },
    error: function (ex) { 
     return false;          
    }
});
```

This ajax call is made from

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {//Ajax call});
```

Comment: When it fails, how does it fail?  What's the error?  Also note that `async: false` is a bad idea.  I'd be surprised if browsers even continue to support that.

Comment: Looks like a weird bug, are you 100% sure it works because you have your Dev tools open? If so, this might be a chrome bug and not your code. I also agree with @David. Never do this, everything that depends on this call should be executed inside the `success: function()`

Comment: Thanks for the rep.. :) I tried with async true.It also results the same.in error block exception get as null

Comment: @SandeepPPillai: But what is actually triggering the error function?  Check the browser's developer tools.  Is there an error on the console?  What is the response from the server?

Comment: @David: When the developer tool is opened there is will not be any error. it works as usual The response from server is just a Boolean value..

Comment: @SandeepPPillai: If the server response is successful then how is it triggering the error callback?  This would only happen in an error response code.

Comment: @David: actually that was confusing me..